# Wallet throws WalletNotReadyError when on remote, but works fine locally

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, walletadapter

I am using the phantom-wallet-adapter in a Next.js app. It works fine and connects to my wallet when running the app locally. However, when running it remotely (for example, when connecting to the deployed frontend, or simply connecting to the IP address and port of my PC from another PC), it keeps giving WalletNotReadyError, even though I have the phantom extension installed on the browser accessing the app.
I have noticed that while running the remote, window.solana is undefined, which, to my understanding, is needed in order to connect the wallet to the app.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was here? I'm having the same problem with NextJS 13 deployed in Docker on AWS.

Comment: Yes. The issue is that the solana wallet adapter refuses to work on HTTP unless it's locally. In order to get it to work make sure you access your next app via HTTPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the solana wallet adapter refuses to work on HTTP unless it's locally. In order to get it to work make sure you access your next app via HTTPS

Comment: i use ngrok. it doesnt work. is it really deploy on website via aws ?

Comment: You can deploy via anything you want as long as the domain is HTTPS and not HTTP.